# Most efficient way to extract mapped array from javascript data array? (Possible with destructuring?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

If I have data in the following format

```
 [{
            letter: "o",
            answer: "orco",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA O. Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien"), ("CON LA O. Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien"), ("CON LA O. Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien")]
        },
        {
            letter: "p",
            answer: "protoss",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA P. Raza ancestral tecnológicamente avanzada que se caracteriza por sus grandes poderes psíonicos del videojuego StarCraft"), ("CON LA P. Raza ancestral tecnológicamente avanzada que se caracteriza por sus grandes poderes psíonicos del videojuego StarCraft")]
        }]
```

and I wanted to retrieve an array of simply the element `letter` (thus in the above, I'd end up with the array `[op]`), what is the most efficient way to do this?  `Array.prototype.map` seems the most logical choice

```
let newArray = dataArray.map(element => element.letter)
```

but I was wondering whether there were a way to do it with destructuring, that is, is there any way to assign an `Array` to the left side of an ES6 destructuring expression?

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the `letter` property for destructuring.

```
let newArray = dataArray.map(({ letter }) => letter);
```